# Starting VPN Connection without Keychain Password Prompt

Tags: network, security, password, keychain, vpn

My IKEv2 VPN client certificates are stored in Keychain. When I initiate a VPN connection, I'm immediately prompted for my Macbook administrator account password before access to the Client certificate stored in Keychain required for the connection is allowed:

[image: Keychain Dialog for Cert Access]

You'll note from reviewing the dialog, there's no option to persistently allow future access by retaining the password

Given that mobile workers use VPNs in public places with cameras everywhere, re-keying this password is not ideal.  Even more so if one's business takes them to countries with authoritarian regimes.

I could allow it always in keychain, but this requires you choosing the binary that is calling the Keychain.  This is where I'm stuck:  ***What binary is responsible for initiating the VPN connection?***

When I double-click the cerrt in Keychain and choose the "Access Control" tab, I'm offered the option to choose a application to persistently allow Keychain access to.  This is why I need the binary that Apple uses to make VPN connections:

[image: Dialog asking for a file to allow]

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the password request? Usually, it should offer you to choose between allowing access "this time" or "always".

Comment: Not offered that option.  I would have **JUMPED** at the opportunity!

Comment: How was the VPN client set up? Which client is it? Which keychain are the certificates stored in? Is the VPN user different from the admin user?

Comment: I use the Apple VPN client and point it to the Cert in Keychain the device uses for authenticating.  Only have a single keychain. Client Certs are pkcs12 format.  Hence probably the cautiousness in requiring a password.

Comment: I don't quite understand your setup. The certificates are either in a PKCS12 store or in the keychain, not both. You always have different keychains. If you look at the entries, on the right it tells you which keychain the object is in: system keychain or your personal login keychain. The certificates should be in your login keychain, as usually this is the keychain that can be accessed without additional authentication once the user has logged in.

Comment: Mikrotik instructed to import the VPN Client certs in PKCS12 format for Apple users.   I choose "***Download***" in the web GUI for RouterOS.  Safarai immediately saw I was downloading a cert and fired-up Keychain which asked me if I wanted to import it.  It was then added to my keychain for "System"

Comment: So, you've imported in from the PKCS12 keystore into keychain. It's now in your keychain, you can safely remove the p12 file. Still, which keychain did you import it into?

Comment: The "system" chain as noted above-

Comment: Then try moving it to the login keychain.

Comment: No good: Mikrotik instructs it's to live in the "System" keychain.  Again, it's possible to persistently allow access without password prompt, but this requires specifying the binary of the Apple binary that initiates the VPN connection.  If I only had that info, I'd be across the finish line.

Comment: Mikrotik? What are you referring to? With regard to the binary, I would tell you if I knew, but maybe [this article about macOS VPN architecture](https://blog.timac.org/2018/0717-macos-vpn-architecture/) can help you.